# Month Sequences and full Month name - SQL Server

Tags: sql, sql-server

I want full month name and proper month sequences in report

[image]

My current query is

```
SELECT RIGHT(CONVERT(VARCHAR(3),GETDATE(),100),8)
```

Answer (score 0):

```
SELECT DATENAME(MONTH, GETDATE()) AS Month
FROM TABLE1 ORDER BY Month(Date)
```

**Ouput**

```
Month
-----
April
```

**Demo**

> http://sqlfiddle.com/#!18/9eecb/14624

**DATENAME (Transact-SQL)**

> Returns a character string that represents the specified datepart of
>   the specified date

**Syntax**

```
DATENAME ( datepart , date )

datepart    Abbreviations
year        yy, yyyy
quarter     qq, q
month       mm, m
dayofyear   dy, y
day         dd, d
week        wk, ww
weekday     dw, w
hour        hh
minute      mi, n
second      ss, s
millisecond ms
microsecond mcs
nanosecond  ns
TZoffset    tz
ISO_WEEK    ISOWK, ISOWW
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use `datename()` function:

```
SELECT datename(mm, getdate()) as Monthname
from table t
order by 1;
```

Answer (score 0):

Presumably, the query you want is something like this:

```
select datename(month, datecol), sum(amount)
from t
where . . . 
group by datename(month, datecol)
order by min(datecol);
```